# Can i do distinct on multiple columns in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a usecase in which i need to count the distinct number of two fields.

Sample :

```
x = LOAD 'testdata' using PigStorage('^A') as (a,b,c,d);

y = GROUP x BY a;

z = FOREACH y {

        **bc = DISTINCT x.b,x.c;**
        dd = DISTINCT x.d;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (a), COUNT(bc), COUNT(dd);
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You were quite close.  The key is to not apply `DISTINCT` to two fields, but instead to apply it to a single composite field that you create:

```
x = LOAD 'testdata' using PigStorage('^A') as (a,b,c,d);
x2 = FOREACH x GENERATE a, TOTUPLE(b,c) AS bc, d
y = GROUP x2 BY a;
z = FOREACH y {
        bc = DISTINCT x2.bc;
        dd = DISTINCT x2.d;
        GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (a), COUNT(bc), COUNT(dd);
};
```

Comment: So we could say that is not possible apply the distinct in each column, instead, we could create a separate distinct and then perform a query!! good and helpfully

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there is no trivial way (like a `GROUP(DISTINCT a)` in MySQL) so you need to split your table to make two counts per row.

```
x = LOAD 'testdata' using PigStorage('^A') as (a,b,c,d);

w1 = FOREACH x GENERATE a, CONCAT(b,c) AS bc;
w2 = FOREACH x GENERATE a, d;

v1 = DISTINCT w1;
v2 = DISTINCT w2;

u1 = GROUP v1 BY a;
u2 = GROUP v2 BY a;

t1 = FOREACH u1 GENERATE group AS a, COUNT(v1.bc);
t2 = FOREACH u2 GENERATE group AS a, COUNT(v2.d);

s = JOIN t1 BY a, t2 BY a;
```

A UDF could simplify this considerably.